# irreducible polynomial $f$ in four variables with complex coefficients such that $f(x^3+y^3+z^3,x^2y+y^2z+z^2x,xy^2+yz^2+zx^2,xyz)=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Let $p,q,r,s \in \mathbb C[x,y,z]$ be defined as
\begin{eqnarray*}
p(x,y,z)&=&x^3+y^3+z^3,\\
q(x,y,z)&=&x^2y+y^2z+z^2x,\\
r(x,y,z)&=&xy^2+yz^2+zx^2,\\
s(x,y,z)&=&xyz.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then how to find an irreducible polynomial (if it exists) $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ such that 
$$f(p(x,y,z), q(x,y,z),r(x,y,z),s(x,y,z))=0,$$ 
i.e. $f(p(x,y,z), q(x,y,z),r(x,y,z),s(x,y,z))$ is the zero polynomial in $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ ?

May be it has something to do with Hilbert Nullstellensatz, but I'm not sure.

Please help.

Comment: Is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(p,q,r,s)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $p$, $q+r$ and $s$ are homogeneous symmetric polynomials, so they are polynomials in the elementary symmetric polynomials
$$e_1:=x_1+x_2+x_3,\qquad e_2:=x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3,\qquad e_3:=x_1x_2x_3.$$
It is not hard to find expressions explicitly;
$$p=e_1^3-3e_1e_2+3e_3,\qquad q+r=e_1e_2-3e_3,\qquad s=e_3.$$
Moreover $q-r=(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$ is alternating and so $(q-r)^2$ is also symmetric; we have
$$(q-r)^2=e_1^2e_2^2-4e_2^3-27e_3^2-4e_1^3e_3+18e_1e_2e_3.$$
From these we can isolate $e_1e_2$, $e_1^3$ and $e_2^3$ to find
\begin{eqnarray*}
e_1e_2&=&q+r+3s.\\
e_1^3&=&p+3q+3r+6s\\
e_2^3&=&-\frac{1}{4}\left((q-r)^2-(e_1e_2)^2+27s^2+4e_1^3s-18(e_1e_2)s\right)\\
&=&qr-ps+3qs+3rs+3s^2.\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Plugging this back into the relation $(e_1e_2)^3-e_1^3e_2^3=0$ yields
$$(q+r+3s)^3-(p+3q+3r+6s)(qr-ps+3qs+3rs+3s^2)=0.$$
This can be expanded to give
$$9s^3+3ps^2-6qrs+p^2s+q^3+r^3-pqr=0.$$

---

It remains to check irreducibility. Let $a,b,c\in\Bbb{C}[x_2,x_3,x_4]$ be such that
$$f
=9x_4^3+3x_1x_4^2-6x_2x_3x_4+x_1^2x_4+x_2^3+x_3^3-x_1x_2x_3
=ax_1^2+bx_1+c.$$
Then $f$ is reducible if and only if either

1. there exists some $d\in\Bbb{C}[x_2,x_3,x_4]$ with $\deg d>0$ that divides $a$, $b$ and $c$; or
2. there exist some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\in\Bbb{C}[x_2,x_3,x_4]$ such that $f=(\alpha x_1+\beta)(\gamma x_1+\delta)$;

or both.

In the first case, comparing coefficients shows that if such a $d$ exists, it is a factor of
$$a=x_4,\qquad b=3x_4^2-x_2x_3,\qquad c=x_2^3+x_3^3+9x_4^3-6x_2x_3x_4,$$
which immediately implies that $\deg d=0$, a contradiction.

In the second case, comparing coefficients shows that
$$\alpha\gamma=x_4,\qquad 
\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma=3x_4^2-x_2x_3,\qquad
\beta\delta=x_2^3+x_3^3+9x_4^3-6x_2x_3x_4,$$
so from the first equality, without loss of generality $\alpha=1$ and $\gamma=x_4$. The last two equalities tell us
$$\deg(\alpha\delta+\beta\gamma)=2
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
\deg\beta+\deg\delta=3,$$
which implies that $\deg\beta=1$ and $\deg \delta=2$. Plug in $\beta=ux_2+vx_3+wx_4$ to find that
$$\delta=\alpha\delta=(3x^2-x_2x_3)-\beta\gamma=(3-w)x_4^2-x_2x_3-ux_2x_4-vx_3x_4,$$
but this contradicts the fact that the product $\beta\delta$ is cubic in $x_2$ and $x_3$. Hence $f$ is irreducible.

---

An alternative way to show that $f$ is irreducible is by showing that there is no quadratic $g\in\Bbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ such that $g(p,q,r,s,y)$. Note that $g$ must be homogeneous. Expressing all products of pairs from $\{p,q,r,s\}$ on the basis of monomials in $\Bbb{C}$ of degree $6$ yields
$$\begin{matrix}
   &x^6 &x^5y &x^5z &x^4y^2&x^4z^2&x^4yz &x^3y^3&x^3y^2z&x^3yz^2&x^2y^2z^2\\
p^2& 1  &     &     &      &      &      & 2    &       &       &         \\
q^2&    &     &     & 1    &      &      &      &       & 2     &         \\
r^2&    &     &     &      & 1    &      &      & 2     &       &         \\
s^2&    &     &     &      &      &      &      &       &       & 1       \\
pq &    & 1   &     &      & 1    &      &      & 1     &       &         \\
pr &    &     &  1  &  1   &      &      &      &       & 1     &         \\
ps &    &     &     &      &      & 1    &      &       &       &         \\
qr &    &     &     &      &      & 1    & 1    &       &       & 3       \\
qs &    &     &     &      &      &      &      & 1     &       &         \\
rs &    &     &     &      &      &      &      &       & 1     &         
\end{matrix}$$
Here we used the fact that $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ are invariant under cyclic shifts of $x$, $y$ and $z$. The coefficients of any quadratic $g\in\Bbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ with $g(p,q,r,s)=0$ must then be in the kernel of the transpose of this $10\times10$-matrix, so it suffices to show that its determinant is nonzero.

Laplace expansion along the first three columns and subsequently along the rows $s^2$, $ps$, $qs$ and $rs$ shows its determinant is the same as that of thr $3\times3$-identity matrix, so $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: I have tried some cubic combinations but nothing works ... could you please elaborate ?